# "illegal start of type" & "class, interface or enum expected"

Tags: java

When I compile following java code it throws `illegal start of type` & `class, interface or enum expected` errors.

Inside Percolation class in following code, a WeightedQuickUnionUF data type belonging to another class is declared. WeightedQuickUnionUF class is stored in a jar file named "algs4.jar" inside current working directory.

I have checked  code several times but can't find out the flaw and completely stuck.

The code is as follows:

```
public class Percolation{
    public static Percolation(int n){
        boolean[][] A=new boolean[n][n];
    }
    int i,j;
    WeightedQuickUnionUF WQUF=new WeightedQuickUnionUF[n*n+2];
    for(i=1;i&lt;=n;i++)
    {
        WQUF.union(0,i);
    }
    for (i=n*n-n+1;i&lt;=n*n;i++)
    {
        WQUF.union(n*n+1,i);
    }
    do {
        i=StdRandom.uniform(n-1)+1;
        j=StdRandom.uniform(n-1)+1;
    } while(A[i][j]!=0)
    open(i,j);
    private static int xyto1D(int x,int y){
        return (n*x+y);
    }
    public static void open(int i,int j){
        A[i][j]=1;
        if(A[i-1][j]==1) {WQUF.union(xyto1D(i-1,j),xyto1D(i,j))};
        if(A[i+1][j]==1) {WQUF.union(xyto1D(i+1,j),xyto1D(i,j))};
        if(A[i][j-1]==1) {WQUF.union(xyto1D(i,j-1),xyto1D(i,j))};
        if(A[i][j+1]==1) {WQUF.union(xyto1D(i,j+1),xyto1D(i,j))};
    }
    public static boolean isOpen(int x,int y){
        return (A[x][y]==1);
    }
    public static boolean isFull(int x,int y){
        return (WQUF.connected(xyto1D(x,y),0));
    }
    public static boolean percolates(){
        for (i=n*n-n+1;i&lt;=n*n;i++)
        {
            if ((isFull(i))&&(isOpen(i))) return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I get following errors during compilation:

```
35 errors found:

File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 7]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 7]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 7]
Error: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 7]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 7]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 7]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 7]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 7]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolati
on.java  
[line: 8]
Error: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 9]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 9]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 9]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 11]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 11]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 11]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 14]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 17]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 18]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 20]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 22]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 23]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 25]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 26]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 27]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 28]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 29]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 30]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 32]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 33]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 35]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 36]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 37]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 37]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 40]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C:\Users\Administrator\algs4\Percolation.java  
[line: 42]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE or not?

Comment: @psjinx Please don't use code formatting for simple titles of things; it is meant only for actual code.

Comment: Okay. I will remember that in future.

Answer (score 2):

You close the constructor in the fourth line, every error is a result of this.

```
    public static Percolation(int n){
        boolean[][] A=new boolean[n][n];
    } // <<--- here
```

Please work on your indentation. If I remember correctly, both eclipse and netbeans have some sort of auto indentation. You would have easily caught it yourself with proper indentation.

Comment: That seems like supposed to be constructor, rather than suposed to be method.

Comment: One more thing is, you can't have `static` modifier for constructors. There are many more problems in the code.

Comment: e.g. `A` is not a field of the class, but used in methods.

Answer (score 1):

Also problem is here: (Apart from lot of other syntax errors, you debug line by line so that you will come to know where and all you are violating Java's syntax rules)

```
WeightedQuickUnionUF WQUF=new WeightedQuickUnionUF[n*n+2];
```

You should change it to:

```
WeightedQuickUnionUF WQUF=new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 do {
i=StdRandom.uniform(n-1)+1;
j=StdRandom.uniform(n-1)+1;
} while(A[i][j]!=0)
```

You need to put the semicolon at the end of while statement.

```
do {
i=StdRandom.uniform(n-1)+1;
j=StdRandom.uniform(n-1)+1;
} while(A[i][j]!=0);
```

There seems many problems with the code. I would suggest you to use Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, every executable code (with exception of initialization) needs to be placed within a block( static or function).

On line 7 of you file however, you have a `for` loop which is in the body of the class, which is invalid. Please put it inside the constructor or some other function.

In fact, the code that you have posted has one more problem. You have declared the constructor static which is not allowed. A constructor cannot be static.

```
public static Percolation(int n) {  // illegal
boolean[][] A = new boolean[n][n];
}
```

Assuming that code starting from line 7 is part of the constructor, here is the code, that should work

```
public class Percolation {
    public Percolation(int n) {
    boolean[][] A = new boolean[n][n];

        int i, j;
        WeightedQuickUnionUF WQUF = new WeightedQuickUnionUF[n * n + 2];


        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
           WQUF.union(0,i);
        }

        for (i=n*n-n+1;i<=n*n;i++){
            WQUF.union(n*n+1,i);
        }

        do{
            i=StdRandom.uniform(n-1)+1;
            j=StdRandom.uniform(n-1)+1;
        } while(A[i][j]!=0); //add this semicolon as well.

        open(i,j);
    }

    private static int xyto1D(int x, int y) {
    return (n * x + y);
    }

    public static void open(int i,int j){
        A[i][j]=1;
        if(A[i-1][j]==1) {WQUF.union(xyto1D(i-1,j),xyto1D(i,j))};
         if(A[i+1][j]==1) {WQUF.union(xyto1D(i+1,j),xyto1D(i,j))};
          if(A[i][j-1]==1) {WQUF.union(xyto1D(i,j-1),xyto1D(i,j))};
           if(A[i][j+1]==1) {WQUF.union(xyto1D(i,j+1),xyto1D(i,j))};
    }

    public static boolean isOpen(int x, int y) {
    return (A[x][y] == 1);
    }

    public static boolean isFull(int x, int y) {
    return (WQUF.connected(xyto1D(x, y), 0));
    }

    public static boolean percolates() {
    for (i = n * n - n + 1; i <= n * n; i++) {
        if ((isFull(i)) && (isOpen(i)))
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: assignment is not the exception to this rule. It's the declaration.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, sry for not being specific. I meant initialization, like private List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();